# std::unordered_map using a template class pointer as a key

Tags: c++, templates, unordered-map

**I'm a beginner for cpp,and I have some codes like this:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>


template<typename T,typename EX>
class Attachable
{
    
    static std::unordered_map<T*,Attachable<T,EX>> attachCaches;

    std::unordered_map<std::string,EX> datas;

    Attachable(T* sender):m_attachedObj(sender)
    {
    }

    bool operator==(const Attachable& other)const
    {
        return m_attachedObj == other.m_attachedObj;
    }
public:

    static Attachable<T,EX> attach(T* sender)
    {
        if(attachCaches.find(sender)==attachCaches.end())
        {
            attachCaches.insert(std::make_pair((sender),Attachable<T,EX>(sender)));
        }

        return attachCaches[(sender)];
    }


    void set(std::string key,EX properties)
    {
        datas.insert(key,properties);
    }

    EX get(std::string key)
    {
        return datas.at(key);
    }

private:
    T* m_attachedObj;
};


class Tester
{
public :
    Tester(){}
};

int main()
{
    Tester* a =new Tester();

    Attachable<Tester,std::string>::attach(a).set("test","typeOfInt");

    std::cout<< Attachable<Tester,std::string>::attach(a).get("test");

}
```

**When I try to compile this code , I will receive an error at ,line 952,at the function called
`emplace(*_First);`**

```cpp
    template <class _Iter, class _Sent>
    void _Insert_range_unchecked(_Iter _First, const _Sent _Last) {
        for (; _First != _Last; ++_First) {
            emplace(*_First);
        }
    }
```

I am trying to using some basic pointer like int,but this still not worked:

```cpp
    int* a =new int(4);

    Attachable<int,std::string>::attach(a).set("test","typeOfInt");

    std::cout<< Attachable<int,std::string>::attach(a).get("test");
```

Comment: Do you really need pointer? `int* a = new int(4);` is code smell.

Comment: [OT]: "data" is already plural, "datas" is incorrect.

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks for your reply ! And sorry for my poor english , I am leaning it too :) ,and for my codes ,what I want is to give every objects at heap an extension value (this is why I need a pointer as key of the hash map ), So I can use the `Attachable<X,XX>::attach(a).set("a key",XXXX);` to set any type of values, so the `int* a =new int(4)` is just for test , I already know this is bad to be an example, anyway ,thank you for your guidance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`attachCaches[(sender)]` may need to default-construct an `Attachabe` object, if it turns out that `sender` is not in the map. But `Attachable` doesn't provide a default constructor. Since you actually know the key is always in the map, you can implement `attach` this way (also more efficient, as it eliminates redundant lookups):

```
static Attachable<T,EX>& attach(T* sender)
{
    auto it = attachCaches.find(sender);
    if (it == attachCaches.end())
    {
        it = attachCaches.emplace(sender, Attachable<T,EX>(sender)).first;
    }

    return it->second;
}
```

Note also how the function now returns `Attachable` by reference. Your original code returned a temporary copy of the map element; then called `set` on that copy; then that copy was destroyed. The original in the map was never updated, so a subsequent `get` didn't find the value passed to `set`.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GP6Wq1oGT)

Comment: You might also remove extra lookup with simply `return attachCaches.emplace(sender, Attachable<T,EX>(sender)).first->second` (the (possibly extra) constructor is cheap here).

Comment: I don't know if anythings wrong , but I can't compile these codes in msvc :(

Comment: What happens when you try? Do you see error messages? What do they say? Seems to [work for me](https://godbolt.org/z/MdKrTjc5h) once I added a previously-missing `#include <string>`

Comment: I was using visual studio on windows , I build a empty c++ project , and create a `main.cpp`, paste these codes and build , then got error with code `LNK2001`  ` and `LNK1120`, they both described as `unresolved external symbol`, **other details is too long to be a comment , so I just paste a shortcut:** `private: static class std::unordered_map<class A *,class Attachable<class A,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char>....$allocator@U?$pair@QEAVA@@V?$Attachable@VA@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@@@std@@@4@@std@@A)`

Comment: You are likely missing this part of my demo: `template<typename T,typename EX> std::unordered_map<T*,Attachable<T,EX>> Attachable<T,EX>::attachCaches;` (outside the class definition).